# Window height and html height inconsistency

Tags: html, css

I am trying to **vertically align** a containing block in a large window by setting the `body` element to **display:table** and then setting three contained blocks to display:table-row with a **fixed height** for the middle block. With `javascript` **window.screen.height** returns 1440px. However, in Safari's developer view the html element's `CSS` properties show height: 1259px. This then offsets my body's vertical alignment.

Should the `html` element not be the same value as window.screen.height?

Comment: Remember that `html` and `body` can have default margins/paddings from the browser stylesheet – eliminate those in your own stylesheet explicitly if you don’t want any surprises.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , eliminated the default styling. I think I'm just trying to figure out if the html element's height is supposed to be identical to window.screen.height

Comment: screen.height is supposed to be the actual pixel height of the physical screen – it has nothing to do with the browser window height (might not be fullscreen, or limited by task bars etc.) nor the actual height of the document. I think you might be rather looking for `window.innerHeight` – have a look at the description of the different properties here, http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window